# Error with creating a filter function

Tags: r, function

sharpening my concepts regarding functions in r, I decided to create a filter function which successfully extracts data based on conditions such as

```
Public <= x , CrimeType == y and Year == z.
```

Somehow I am just getting an empty tibble and I am not able to debug where I went wrong. I am attaching a picture of the structure of my dataset and the code I used. Looking forward to your kind advise and guidance regarding this.

[image: structure of the data frame]

[image: the code I used with the result I got]

Comment: Please can you post both data and code as plain text (using _e.g._ `dput(myDataFrame)` for data), not pictures, so users can copy/paste it when preparing their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CrimeFilter <- function(x, y, z){
    for(i in seq_along(CrimeAnnual2012_2015Updated)){
            return(subset(CrimeAnnual2012_2015Updated,
                          Public <= x & CrimeType == y & Year == z))
    }
}

CrimeFilter(100, "Murder", "012012")
```